# Handling alternate spellings of a personal name

Tags: orthography, names, cmos

Dealing with a text that mentions several times the architectural historian Siegfried Giedion. A number of Giedion's books feature his first name as "Sigfried" and others as "Siegfried." The original text (from 1954 - this is a new edition) uses the first name "Siegfried" once and I'm inclined, as editor, to note "Sigfried Giedion" as well, as it's approximately twice as common.  Where is CMOS's guidance on how to handle this in indexing his name and in any footnotes where he and/or his works are to be mentioned?

Should it simply be "Siegfried/Sigfried Giedion" in every case or just in the index (Giedion, Siegfried/Sigfried)? Giedion was published by highly reputable presses under both names.

Comment: Just choose ***one*** spelling and stick with it - but mention the alternative spelling the first time if you think it's important. In your actual text - there's no point in putting both spellings in an *index* entry (it's not like your reader would be unable to find it if he searched for the spelling you *didn't* choose).

Comment: See this question on Academia SE: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/50127/common-practice-for-references-to-articles-with-different-spellings-of-authors (it doesn't discuss indexing, but I think that's the simplest aspect - have one preferred spelling in the index and cross-ref if it's not obvious.)

Comment: The spelling should be left up **to the person**, for pity's sake. So, it does not matter what some publisher or critic says. The person knows best,

Comment: @Lambie - The text is from 1954 when both the author and Giedion were in their senior years.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should pick whichever is most common or standard, but (when multiple spellings are common) it is worth noting the two variant spellings in the text. [If Ngram Viewer is to be believed](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Siegfried+Giedion%2CSigfried+Giedion&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), "Sigfried" is the more common choice in this instance.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of all that, the valuable Ngram tool included, and would advise the same, however, in this instance I really must know how to handle both because the author describing Giedion uses the slightly less common "Siegfried" where he references one of Giedion's books (one where the publisher also used Siegfried, though more of his titles are under Sigfried Giedion). ~40K Google hits for "Siegfried Giedion" and ~100K for Sigfried Giedion.  So it's not an overwhelming preference that renders the alternate negligible. I'm responsible for indexing and editor notes, including one on S.G.

Comment: @Typothalamus You need to include in your question the fact that you can't change the text in question and that the text uses the less common spelling exclusively. The question is very incomplete without that information.

Comment: I've added the suggested information: The original text (from 1954 - this is a new edition) uses the first name "Siegfried" once and I'm inclined, as editor, to note "Sigfried Giedion" as well, as it's approximately twice as common.

Comment: @Typothalamus That makes this question very specific to one discipline (typesetting  or creating a new edition of an existing text) and thus likely a poor fit for ELU.

Comment: And yet ELU is enormously popular and/or quite SEO optimized – it attracts responses, trumping by a wide margin participation rates on the Chicago Manual of Style's forum and other StackExchanges. So if not here, which has proven successful, may I ask where?